# Xcode 5 Link Document Type

Tags: xcode

Am following tutorial at

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/email-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app

To link a document type to my application so that my application is responsible for opening up of that document.

XCode 5 works very different... Under your Target, Info tab is a "Document Types" line... am not sure how to use this, is there a sample for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I'm sure you've either figured this out or moved on, but a little tip for most of these tutorials: you can often download the completed code from the website.  I did so, and loaded it up in Xcode 5.0, and it works fine.  Here's a screenshot of the plist entries (that's under Resources/ScaryBugs-Info.plist) for Document and Export:

[image: Document plist entries]

Another way to change the Document types in Xcode is via the Project Info (select the project in the Navigator, then the target in the projects and targets list, then the info tab).  Here's a screenshot of what that stuff looked like for me:

[image: Document project info entries]

Comment: If like me, you can't read the screenshot above, click the link in the answer by Sam B, has similar screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another very helpful link straight from apple support. Watch the screenshot they have under Example and literally replicate everything from this screenshot and just change their custom extension from catinfo to pdf, ttf, xml or whatever you like

NOTE: Make sure you test this on actual iphone / ipad and not on simulator.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html